# How to create an android app to create an facebook event at my own group?

Tags: android, facebook, events

I have a problem to solve.
I want to create an event at my facebook group which is created by my android app.

This is the following code:

> JSONObject event = new JSONObject();
>   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
>   bundle.putString("method","events.create");
>   event.put("page_id",***groupid***);
>   event.put("name", "App event test");
>   event.put("location", "locationtest");
>   event.put("start_time", "2011-05-14T10:13:00");
>   event.put("end_time", "2011-05-15T10:20:00");
>   event.put("privacy_type", "OPEN");
>   bundle.putString("event_info",event.toString());
>   facebook.request(bundle);

When I executed the app,I just could see my event which I created at my event list,but I couldn't see the event at my new feeds and the new feeds of my group.
I don't know how to solve it.

Please give me your points of views~thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are missing is the POST on the line "facebook.request(bundle);"
Try changing it to "facebook.request(bundle, "POST");"